# Pandas DataFrame combine rows by column value, where Date Rows are NULL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-camelot

**Scenerio:**
Parse the PDF Bank statement and transform into clean and formatted csv file.

**What I've tried:**
I manage to parse the pdf file(tabular format) using camelot library but failed to produce the desired result in sense of formatting.

**Code:**

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd

tables = camelot.read_pdf('test.pdf', pages = '3')

for i, table in enumerate(tables):
    print(f'table_id:{i}')
    print(f'page:{table.page}')
    print(f'coordinates:{table._bbox}')

tables = camelot.read_pdf('test.pdf', flavor='stream', pages = '3')

columns = df.iloc[0]

df.columns = columns
df = df.drop(0)
df.head()

for c in df.select_dtypes('object').columns:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace('$', '')
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace('-', '')

def convert_to_float(num):
    try:
        return float(num.replace(',',''))
    except:
        return 0

for col in ['Deposits', 'Withdrawals', 'Balance']:
    df[col] = df[col].map(convert_to_float)
```

**My_Result:**
[image]

**Desired_Output:**
[image]

The logic I came up with is to move those rows up i guess n-1 if date column is NaN i don't know if this logic is right or not.Can anyone help me to sort out this properly?

I tried pandas groupby and aggregation functions but it only merging the whole data and removing NaN and duplicate dates which is not suitable because every entry is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Transform` -

```
df.loc[~df.Date.isna(), 'group'] = 1
g = df.group.fillna(0).cumsum()
df['Description'] = df.groupby(g)['Description'].transform(' '.join)
new_df =  df.loc[~df['Date'].isna()]
```

Comment: It worked for joining the rows but now Date column is gone.Result: 1.0  CHRYSLER CAPITAL PAYMENT 0023582513  0.00  469.88  51.15 img: https://ibb.co/pfVv8WS

Comment: That's why I dropped extra rows see new_df (LAST LINE). Sorry, I was dropping based on description col instead of date. It'll work now test it once.

Comment: It's still repeating on x-axis img: https://ibb.co/BNYBbmJ